# Provided token is not a UUID error with Gitlab CI

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, code-coverage, codecov

I am trying to do code coverage for a flask app in Python and uploading it on the `codecov.io` platform. I am trying to upload it directly via Gitlab CI, but it doesn't happen. It keeps throwing the following error:

```
HTTP 400
Provided token is not a UUID.
```

I created an account on `codecov.io` and connected it to my gitlab account and selected a repository to work with. I added the token as an environment variable in gitlab CI

[image]

My CI file is:

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

variables:
    CODECOV_TOKEN: $CODECOV_TOKEN

stages:
    - coverage
    - deploy

coverage:
    stage: coverage
    before_script:
        - apt-get -y update
        - apt-get -y install curl python3-pip python3.7 zip
        - python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        - python3.7 -V
        - pip3.7 install -r requirements.txt

    script:
        - coverage run -m pytest
        - coverage report -m

    after_script:
       - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -t $CODECOV_TOKEN
```

The error screenshot:

[image]

But, when I did `bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -t <token>` from the linux terminal, it was successfully uploaded.

What is the mistake that I am doing?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `variables:` section from your .gitlab-ci.yml?

Comment: @MaxSmolens `HTTP 400
 Please provide the repository token to upload reports via `-t :repository-token`

Comment: What if in addition to removing the `variables:` section, you uncheck "Protected" next to CODECOV_TOKEN in the CI Variables settings?

Comment: Hey @MaxSmolens, apologies for getting back late to you. Unchecking the "Protected" worked. If you could make it as your answer, I would be glad to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot of the GitLab CI/CD variables shows that the `CODECOV_TOKEN` variable is "[protected](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#protect-a-custom-variable)": GitLab exports the variable only to pipelines running on protected branches and tags.

When running your pipeline on an unprotected branch, `CODECOV_TOKEN` is not set, and the codecov script fails.

To make the variable available to pipelines running on all branches, edit the variable and uncheck "Protect variable."